# using the form helper for multilpe records

Tags: cakephp-1.3, formhelper, multiple-records

I have a table called `specs`. I need to edit multiple rows from it in one form and save it at once.

```
// table structure
specs [id, name, value, owner_id]
// controller part
$data = $this->Spec->find('all'); // skipping the conditions and other sub-code
$data = set::combine(...);
/*
result, keyed using the spec[id] column.
array (
  [3] = array(id=>...),
  [22] = array(id=>...)
)
*/
```

Now I'm not sure how to continue.
I know how to build a form ready to CREATE new multiple records(Model.{n}.fieldname), but how can i create an "edit" form that will allow the `saveAll()`?

trying to iterate through the result array gets the form close.. but i can't see the values of fields in the input elements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

In the controller:

```
public function edit() {
    $products = $this->Product->find('all');
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Product->saveAll($this->data['Product'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('ok');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('not ok');
        }
    } else {
        $this->data['Product'] = Set::extract($products, '{n}.Product');
    }
    $this->set(compact('products'));
}
```

In the view:

```
echo $this->Session->flash();

echo $this->Form->create('Product');

foreach ($products as $i => $product) {
    echo $this->Form->input("$i.id");
    echo $this->Form->input("$i.name");
}

echo $this->Form->end('Save');
```

PS: I think you can adapt my `Product` example to your needs can't you? : )